# Python function __setattr__ and __getattr__

Tags: python

This program worked, but when I delete the **getattr** or **setattr**, then problem comes, and id, name cannot be found.
Why would this happen, and when does the program runs the **setattr**? I used debug mode, and pined, but it didn't goes to the function.

Thanks!!!

```
class E(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(r"'Model' object has no attribute '%s'" % key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

e = E(id='123', name='abc')
print(e.id)
print(e.name)
```

Comment: The `__getattr__` enables you to access keys with dot notation, removing `__getattr__`, you can still use `E` as a regular dict, `e['id']`, removing `__setattr__` doesn’t matter as dict superclass has its own definition of `__setattr__`

Answer (score -1):

each object that inherit from **dict** must implement __ **getattr** __ __ and __ **setattr** __ , the  __ **setattr** __ is called when you use [ ] , such as e["key1"] = "bla bla"

Comment: Nope - the `__getattr__`/`__setattr__` here are being used to implement attribute lookup on a dict by key instead of index lookup - they're not *required* outside of performing that role.

Comment: when you are creating dict like object i assume that you want to use lookup by key and not by index , that is if you want to use your object like a true dict. so yes - they are required .

Comment: Err again - no. You can just use `self['x']` or `self[1]` or whatever which is implemeted by `__getitem__` - implementing `__getattr__` allows customising what happens when something like `obj.x` is used where `x` is not an attribute already present on that object...

Comment: Ahh - easy to do. No worries :)